# Azure pipeline cannot find requirements.txt file

Tags: python, azure-devops

I am trying to set up a build pipeline for my python project in Azure Devops. But, I keep getting an error when it tries to install dependencies:

```
ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'
```

I have a `requirments.txt` file in the root directory of the repo. Is that the right place? From what I've read it should be. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have not provided enough information. Possibly, some process is not running in the directory you expected it to.

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your pipeline? So that people can further investigate your question.

Answer (score 2):

> ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'

Based on the error message, it seems that `requirements.txt` file does not exist in the path where the command is executed.

You could try the following two methods:

1.You can specify the path of the file in the command：

For example:

**File structure：**

[image]

**Pipeline command:**

```
  - task: CmdLine@2
    displayName: Command Line Script
    inputs:
      script: pip install -r $(build.sourcesdirectory)/requirements.txt --index-url $PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL
```

2.You can specify a specific working path in the Pipeline task.

```
workingDirectory: $(build.sourcesdirectory) #the folder path contains the file
```

For example:

```
  - task: CmdLine@2
    displayName: Command Line Script
    inputs:
      script: pip install -r requirements.txt --index-url $PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL
      workingDirectory: $(build.sourcesdirectory)
```